# Make a wall that boost speed unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

So... I know it must be a pretty straight forward kind of thing, but I'm stuck on that for days, basically what I need, is that when a ball hit a wall (collider), it starts accelerating towards a direction, as picture bellow, but I need to do it using physics, I can't just interpolate the position.

[image: Exemplification]

Comment: Use [Rigidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) or [Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html).

Comment: add a box trigger, and while in trigger addforce

Comment: You should always post some code to show what you've tried.

Comment: You should 1. rotate the Rigidbody so its forward direction is parallel to the ground, then add a force in this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first need a vector parallel to the ground!

You can use [`Collider.ClosestPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPoint.html) in order to find the closest point on the walls collider to the ball Position.

From this you then know a plane normal for your ground/wall so you can then use [`Vector3.ProjectOnPlane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html) in order to convert the usual move direction into one parallel to the ground.

```c#
private void FixedUpdate () 
{
    var ballRb = ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    var wallCollider = Wall.GetComponent<Collider>();
    var hitPoint = wallCollider.ClosestPoint(ballRb.position);

    // normal of ground (= vector from hitPoint to ball)
    var groundNormal = (ballRb.position - hitPoint).normalized;

    // project the given velocity onto the ground
    var newVelocity = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(ballRb.velocity, groundNormal);

    // optionally increase the speed of needed e.g.
    //var newDirection = newVelocity.normalized;
    //var newMagnitude = newVelocity.magnitude * 1.1f; // or any multiplication or addition factor
    //newVelocity = newDirection * newMagnitude;

    // and finally reassign the new velocity
    ballRb.velocity = newVelocity; 
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear and this provides a good start point*